# Android 5.0 does not respect view's margins

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view, android-5.0-lollipop

I have an app that runs well in any version of android, but in Lollipop seems that all views don't respect any margin or padding.
Does anyone know why??

Thanks in advance.

I'm declaring the CardView like this:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/card_view1"
android:background="@color/backgroundItem"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
card_view:cardCornerRadius="0dp"
android:layout_weight="1">
```

Comment: Code and screenshots are going to be necessary to figure out your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Per the [CardView documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/CardView.html):

> Note that, if you specify exact dimensions for the CardView, because of the shadows, its content area will be different between platforms before L and after L. By using api version specific resource values, you can avoid these changes. Alternatively, If you want CardView to add inner padding on platforms L and after as well, you can set [setUseCompatPadding(boolean)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/CardView.html#setUseCompatPadding(boolean)) to `true`.

Comment: Please add code to your question, not as a comment.